# Multi-line Filebeat templates don’t work with filebeat.inputs - type: filestream

Tags: filestream, filebeat

I ran into a multiline processing problem in Filebeat when the filebeat.inputs: parameters specify type: filestream - the logs of the file stream are not analyzed according to the requirements of multiline. pattern: '^[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', in the output, I see that the lines are not added to the lines, are created new single-line messages with individual lines from the log file.

If you specify type: log in the file bat.inputs: parameters, then everything works correctly, in accordance with the requirements of multiline. pattern: '^[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' - a multiline message is created.

What is not correctly specified in my config?

```
filebeat.inputs:
 
     - type: filestream
 
       enabled: true
 
       paths:
         - C:\logs\GT\TTL\*\*.log
       fields_under_root: true
       fields:
         instance: xml
         system: ttl
         subsystem: GT
         account: abc
       multiline.type: pattern
       multiline.pattern: '^\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
       multiline.negate: true
       multiline.match: after
```

Answer (score 2):

To get it working you should have something like this:

```
filebeat.inputs:
 
     - type: filestream
 
       enabled: true
 
       paths:
         - C:\logs\GT\TTL\*\*.log
       fields_under_root: true
       fields:
         instance: xml
         system: ttl
         subsystem: GT
         account: abc
       parsers:
         - multiline:
             type: pattern
             pattern: '^\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
             negate: true
             match: after
```

There are 2 reasons why this works:

1. The general documentation at the time of this writing regarding multiline handling is not updated to reflect changes done for fileinputstream type. You can find information regarding setting up multiline for fileinputstream under parsers on this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-filestream.html
2. The documentation I just mentioned above is also wrong (at least at the time of this writing). The example shows configuring the multiline parsers without indenting its children, which will not work as the parser will not initialize any of the values underneath it. This issue is also being discussed here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-filestream-input-parsers-multiline-fails/290543/13 and I expect it will be fixed sometime in the future.